# Check if project file exists in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core webapp and it's common to render .cshtml files by using code like this (if you are new to ASP.NET Core please notice a .cshtml file is HTML code with embed C# code under the '@' prefix). The most common code when rendering a .csthml view on any section of the web is like this, and the path is always a file of our Visual Studio 2022 solution:

```
<body>
    <partial>
        @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Shared/Forms/_ContactForm.cshtml")
    </partial>
</body>
```

Our main problem is that .cshtml files are frequently renamed, or moved to another sub-directory since the project is growing, and then all references to a path fails and we have no notice until a user run and check the corresponding sub-page of the website.

I'm sure the problem is independent of using ASP.NET Core or another framework, so any general solution could fit here: ¿How can we ensure we get a ***COMPILER*** error when a project file path doesn't exists anymore? ¿any other idea based on our particular case? Most of issues are derived from this file paths and it's really annoying.

Comment: look up how to precompile views for your version

Comment: _we have no notice until a user run_ it seems a very bad project management pattern to me. You SHOULD know about these changes before they happen

Comment: Just write unit tests which will query corresponding pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can we ensure we get a COMPILER error when a project file path doesn't exists anymore

It can be quite cumbersome. AFAIK some IDEs like ReSharper/Rider try to implement similar checks but even theirs attempts far from perfect (at least in my experience I have seen a lot of false positives for example). But you can always look into writing into your own [Roslyn analyzer](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-to-write-a-roslyn-analyzer/) which will take into account the project structure.

> any other idea based on our particular case

I would argue that easier and more robust in general approach would to use infrastructure provided by ASP.NET Core for [integration tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#basic-tests-with-the-default-webapplicationfactory) and just write tests which will ensure that corresponding pages at least return success status code. Example from docs:

```cs
public class BasicTests 
    : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Program>>
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Program> _factory;

    public BasicTests(WebApplicationFactory<Program> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData("/")]
    [InlineData("/Index")]
    [InlineData("/About")]
    [InlineData("/Privacy")]
    [InlineData("/Contact")]
    public async Task Get_EndpointsReturnSuccessAndCorrectContentType(string url)
    {
        // Arrange
        var client = _factory.CreateClient();

        // Act
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

        // Assert
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Status Code 200-299
        Assert.Equal("text/html; charset=utf-8", 
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think unit test over files involved at every task checking if exists is the best solution by now. I was looking for any kind of authomatic checking, or library to check path before using it, but thanks anyway, I'll take this solution in account